# Git duplicates commit files

Tags: eclipse, git, aptana, git-commit

I'm using Aptana plugin for Eclipse. When I try to commit, it doubles file, i.e one exactly file appears couple times. If I have 10 files to commit, it shows 20 files (1 file 2 times). I tried close and open project, Clean by Eclipse (`Project` menu -> `Clean`), Refresh project. Not helped. Even it shows one file 3 times. How can I show files correctly, only once?

**EDIT**
It's screenshot of duplicated files:
[image]

Comment: Could you show  a screenshot illustrating the exact Eclipse view which displays multiple files?

Comment: @VonC I've added screenshot which displays multiple files.

Comment: But I don't see one single duplicate file in your screenshot... Am I missing one?

Comment: @VonC Sorry, updated screenshot.

Comment: Just in case, can you try and play with the resource filter, as in https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=398880#c1?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue like that:

1. I've deleted project form Eclipse.
2. Then I've imported project from locally.

But it's temporary solution. After couple successful commit, files are duplicated again. And I don't want to delete and import project each time before commit.